# ng-admin filters change key

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I want to change the search fields on the filter (list view).
This is the code :

```
filters([
          nga.field('project', 'reference')
                .label('Project')
                .targetEntity(project)
                .targetField(nga.field('nome'))
                .remoteComplete(true, {
                    refreshDelay: 200,
                    searchQuery: function(search) { return { q: search }; }
                })
        ])
```

But the query is 
http://localhost:3000/days?_order=DESC&_sort=id&admin=1&limit=30&offset=0&project=138475ABC48

I want the name of the project in the query not the ID.

Any suggestion ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.targetEntity(nga.entity('projects').identifier(nga.field('name')))